# Finite dimensional Banach algebras whose $K_{0}$ group is a non trivial finite group

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras, idempotents, k-theory

Motivated [by this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229593/k-theory-of-finite-dimensional-banach-algebras) we ask

> Is there a finite dimensional Banach algebra $A$ such that $K_{0}(A)$ is a  nontrivial finite group?

I understand from the  above link and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624250/k-theory-of-finite-dimenional-banach-algebras) that any such algebra should be non unital.